# Active Directory Access Token expire detection

Tags: c#, active-directory, access-token

I am using this singleton pattern on accessToken. For preventing unnecessary token call to login.windows service.

As you see if I have access token, I am serving existing token to my Code.
My problem is when I retrieve token first time. There is no Expire Time or any information. 
This Expire on information always same as **request date** :

[image]

```cs
private static string accessToken_;

private static string AccessToken
{
    get
    {
        if (accessToken_ == null)
        {
            accessToken_ = GetAccessToken();
        }
        return accessToken_;
    }
}


private static string GetAccessToken()
{
    string AadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";

    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(AadInstance, aadTenantId));
    ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecretKey);

    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, clientCredential).Result;

    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

And then really I cannot know when my token will expire?!
For fixing this problem I have this code block on Exception Catch. 
And I think it is not correct design. Do you have another information with suitable design? :

```cs
private static CellSet ExecuteOlapCellSet(string mdxQuery)
{
try
{
.... method codes here...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //25 November: unauthorized, probably token expired.
    if (e.InnerException != null && e.InnerException.Message.Contains("(401)"))
    {
        accessToken_ = GetAccessToken();
        //call same method Again here
        ExecuteOlapCellSet(mdxQuery);
    }

    Utils.LogError(ErrorVariables.Error105, e.InnerException ?? e);
    throw new AnalystServiceException(ErrorVariables.Error105, e);
}
}
```

Comment: That expiry-time is in 8 minutes, so I doubt it's the same as the request-time. Have you considered the time-zone offsets?

Comment: Thank you contribution @J.Steen Really it is same as current datetime.

Comment: But it isn't. That time is in the future. Now, 7 minutes. This is what the time is NOW, in UTC (offset 00:00): `2019-11-25 09:57:35 +00:00`

Comment: Wow! Time zone is 00:00 I havent consider it ! it means this token has 2 hours life time! Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what are you achieving with this code. With the code, you also need to check the token expiry. Instead of writing the custom code, you can rely on `TokenCache` which caches the token in-process memory if not defined as second parameter of  `AuthenticationContext` or defining the second parameter as `TokenCache.DefaultShared`. You can read the details at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.tokencache?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Thank you for sharing information @user1672994 My aim is use token in life time So no need to acquire token again on each request. But when token expired, Yes I have to acquire it again. By J. Steen helpful information. I did it. I could not see Time Zone information.